# A normal subgroup of a matrix such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I am working on the below problem:

Let $G = \{\begin{pmatrix}
a & c\\
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}\ | a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, ab \neq 0\}$, a group under matrix multiplication. Find a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ denotes the multiplicative group of real numbers.

My approach so far has been to first find a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, and then try to construct an isomorphism between $G/N$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$.

One such normal subgroup is given by $N = \{\begin{pmatrix}
d & 0\\
0 & e
\end{pmatrix}\ | d,e \in \mathbb{R}, de \neq 0\}$. It's easy to check that this is indeed a normal subgroup. But, the problem with this, and any other normal subgroup I end up constructing, is that now a typical element of $G/N$ looks like $gn = \begin{pmatrix}
ad & ce\\
0 & be
\end{pmatrix}$, with $a,b,e,d \neq 0$, where $g, n$ are matrices in  $G$ and $N$, respectively. This isn't promising in constructing an isomorphism between $G/N$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$. In particular, it has more than two "free" elements -- I was hoping for a matrix with only two "free" entries, each nonzero, so that I could just send that matrix to the pair of those elements, which will necessarily be an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\times} \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$.

Is there a better way to approach this than trying to come up with a specific isomorphism? Or, is there a way I can guide myself to the right desired isomorphism?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
    \newcommand{\im}{\mathop{\rm Im}\nolimits}
  $

Consider the group homomorphism $\phi$ that sends $$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto (a,c) \in \mathbb{R}^* \times \mathbb{R}^*
$$

You should check this is a group homomorphism. The kernel of this homomorphism is the set 
$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
: b \in \mathbb{R}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

The kernel of a group homormorphism is a normal subgroup and by the first isomorphism theorem we have that $G/\ker\phi \cong \im \phi$. Thus, we have that the $\im\phi = \mathbb{R}^* \times \mathbb{R}^*$, so we get that $G/N \cong \mathbb{R}^* \times \mathbb{R}^*$ if $$
N = \begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
: b \in \mathbb{R}
\end{Bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Oh boy. I can't believe I didn't see to use the First isomorphism theorem. Thanks! That's a big help, potapeno!